# SharePoint Web Template 12001

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

My Sharepoint IIS site's Disk Drive has died, the SQL is on a different server, I have managed to make exports of the sites to restore, and successfully restored some of them, but the main one I can't get to install because WebTemplate 12001 is not the Template of the site I am restoring too, I have made sites with all the templates, but can't get it working.  Does anyone have any idea what template 12001 actually is named, or its lettered ID?

Answer (score 0):

Template 12001 Is a Team Foundation Server Project Portal Template and can be installed by going to Team Foundation Server Administration Console > Extensions For SharePoint, and follow the install instructions.